# How to deal with counter resets in ClickHouse?

Tags: time-series, clickhouse

I try to use the ClickHouse to store time series data. Precisely, accumulated counters. They behave the same as in Prometheus. Regrettably, I have been unable to locate any examples demonstrating how ClickHouse can deal with such data. For example, there is no article or function that covers counter resets as described in https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/hyperfunctions/counter-aggregation/. Can anyone provide an example of how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I handle counter resets via

```sql
SELECT
  runningDifference(v) AS d,
  if(d < 0, d + toInt64(pow(2,32) - 1), d) as value
```